# Remove or relax the limit on flags per-day in review queues

Tags: feature-request, review-queues, flags, triage

I would like to request that, when flagging a question as "Unsalvageable" through the review triage queue, it not count towards our daily flag limit.

For example, there was just an instance of a question in the triage queue that was clearly unsalvageable, but I was unable to flag it as such. My only option was to click "Skip," as I had already flagged 10 posts for the day.

Comment: Every 10 helpful flags you raise you get 1 more flag per day permanently increasing up to eventually 100

Comment: Thanks for the explanation @Magisch, that explains a lot, out of curiosity could someone explain why my question would have been downvoted 4 times. As I understand it downvoting is for questions which don't show research effort, are unclear, or not useful. I did search meta before posting this question and while there where questions regarding flagging limits and reviewing after limits have been reached I couldn't find anything specifically as a feature request for the flagging limit to be overridden from within the triage queue itself...

Comment: I can understand if people disagree with the request to override flag limits in the triage queue but given the stated purpose of down voting wouldn't a comment or answer be more appropriate for disagreeing with a question rather than down voting. Not complaining just curious.

Comment: Voting is different on meta. DVs may merely indicate disagreement, especially for a feature-request. DVs on meta also don't cost you any Rep points and do not count towards any automated bans, btw.

Comment: So is that why the down votes from this meta question don't seem to have affected my rep. Good to know, didn't realise that until now, thanks @Magisch

Comment: Starting at 10 flags/day, if you use all of your flags each day and all of them are marked helpful shortly after you raise them, you can reach the maximum number of flags per day, 100, on the 23 day. Obviously, it will probably be a bit longer than this, as there are real-world inefficiencies (e.g. some flags will be declined/disputed, some will be pending for a longer period of time).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you flag successfully your flag limit will increase. Show us you can do things right and we'll let you do more.

If, however you flagged 10 things incorrectly we need to stop you as soon as possible and not let you continue to make unnecessary work for the rest of us.